# Java how to pass JSON object over a Socket

Tags: java, android, json, sockets

I have a Java ServerSocket that (for now takes input from a keyboard).  I am attempting to turn it into JSON, pass it over a socket and read it in an Android application.  Eventually I will be getting real messages.  The issue is, when I run the application, the code seems to hang in the client on the in.readLine();
No exceptions are thrown, but the print message after in.readLine is never triggered.
I am not sure how to pass JSON over a socket, and grab it on the client side.

Server:

```
public void run(){
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try{
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Please enter your input: ");
                String input = scanner.nextLine();

                out = new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                System.out.println("Input was : " + input);
                json.put("message", input);
                json.put("message2", "A second message");                

                System.out.println(json.toString());
                out.write(json.toString());
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Client (Android)

```
public void run() {

                        Log.i("CHCI_FRAGMENT", "run of ChciInnerMessageLoop");
                        // create a new Client Socket.
                        try {
                            //10.0.2.2 local machine address
                            // sluggo IP:  140.102.98.76
                            // my IP 10.4.31.254
                            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
                            in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                            PrintWriter out =
                                    new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                            while(!"end".equals(socketMessage)) {
                                Log.i("CHCI_FRAGMENT", "LIne 213 ");
                                socketMessage = in.readLine();
                                Log.i("CHCI_FRAGMENT", "LIne 215 ");
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(socketMessage);
                                Log.i("CHCI_FRAGMENT", "LIne 217");
                                runOnUiThread(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                     //   routeMessage(socketMessage);
                                        routeMessage(jsonObject);
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            //TODO
                            Log.i("CHCI_FRAGMENT", "Exception " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e){
                            Log.i("CHCI_FRAGMENT", "JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                        }catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.i("CHCI_FRAGMENT", "JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual.

You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines.

Use a `PrintWriter`, and change `out.write(...)` to `out.println(...)`.

And don't create a new `PrintWriter` every time around the loop.